# Xtext left recursion issue in an expression language

Tags: java, grammar, xtext, antlr3, left-recursion

I've been recently working on a small demo expression grammar in Xtext:

### The Grammar

```
grammar org.example.expressions.Expressions with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals

generate expressions "http://www.example.org/expressions/Expressions"

ExpressionsModel:
    elements+=AbstractElement*;

AbstractElement:
    Variable | EvalExpression;

Variable:
    'var' name=ID '=' expression=Expression;

EvalExpression:
    'eval' expression=Expression;

/*-----------------------------------EXPRESSIONS-----------------------------------*/
//Note that expressions on the same precedence get grouped into a single rule, but not necessarily into the same AST node.
//Examples of this pattern are compound rules such as the AddOrSubExpression, or the ComparisonOrInExpression

Expression:
    ConditionalExpression;

ConditionalExpression returns Expression:
    OrExpression ({ConditionalExpression.condition=current} '?' trueExp=OrExpression ':' falseExp=OrExpression)*;

OrExpression returns Expression:
    AndExpression ({BinaryExpression.left=current} operator='||' right=AndExpression)*;

AndExpression returns Expression:
    BinOrExpression ({BinaryExpression.left=current} operator='&&' right=BinOrExpression)*;

BinOrExpression returns Expression:
    BinXorExpression ({BinaryExpression.left=current} operator='|' right=BinXorExpression)*;

BinXorExpression returns Expression:
    BinAndExpression ({BinaryExpression.left=current} operator='^' right=BinAndExpression)*;

BinAndExpression returns Expression:
    EqualityExpression ({BinaryExpression.left=current} operator='&' right=EqualityExpression)*;

EqualityExpression returns Expression:
    ComparisonOrInExpression ({BinaryExpression.left=current} operator=('==' | '!=') right=ComparisonOrInExpression)*;

ComparisonOrInExpression returns Expression:
    BitShiftExpression (({BinaryExpression.left=current} operator=('<' | '>' | '<=' | '>=') right=BitShiftExpression) // ComparisonExpression
    | ({InExpression.left=current} 'in' (right=BitShiftExpression | ('[' openRangeList+=OpenRangeValue (','
    openRangeList+=OpenRangeValue)* ']'))) // InExpression
    )*;

OpenRangeValue:
    lowBound=Expression ('..' highBound=Expression)?;

BitShiftExpression returns Expression:
    AddOrSubExpression ({BinaryExpression.left=current} operator=('<<' | '>>') right=AddOrSubExpression)*;

AddOrSubExpression returns Expression:
    MulOrDivExpression ({BinaryExpression.left=current} operator=('+' | '-') right=MulOrDivExpression)*;

MulOrDivExpression returns Expression:
    PowExpression ({BinaryExpression.left=current} operator=('*' | '/' | '%') right=PowExpression)*;

PowExpression returns Expression:
    BitSliceExpression ({BinaryExpression.left=current} operator='**' right=BitSliceExpression)*;

BitSliceExpression returns Expression:
    FieldOperationExpression ({BitSliceExpression.operand=current} '[' highBound=Expression ':' lowBound=Expression ']')*;

FieldOperationExpression returns Expression:
    UnaryExpression (({CollectionAccess.operand=current} '[' index=Expression ']') // CollectionAccessExpression
    | ({FunctionCallExpression.targetObject=current} '.' name=ID '(' (params+=Expression (','
    params+=Expression)*)? ')') // FieldAccessFunction
    | ({FieldAccessExpression.targetObject=current} '.' fieldIdentifier=ID))*; // FieldAccessExpression

UnaryExpression returns Expression:
    PrimaryExpression
    | {UnaryExpression} operator=UnaryOperator operand=PrimaryExpression;

PrimaryExpression returns Expression:
    '(' Expression ')'
    | FunctionCallExpression
    | CompileHasExpression
    | StaticRefrencePathExpression
    | {Expression} NullRefrenceExperession
    | StringConstantExpression
    | BoolConstantExpression
    | IntConstantExpression;

FunctionCallExpression:
    name=ID '(' (params+=Expression (',' params+=Expression)*)? ')';

CompileHasExpression:
    'compile' 'has' staticRefPath=StaticRefrencePathExpression;

StaticRefrencePathExpression:
    (globalScope?='::')? (identifiers+=ID ('::' identifiers+=ID)*);

NullRefrenceExperession:
    'null';

IntConstantExpression:
    value=INT;

StringConstantExpression:
    value=STRING;

BoolConstantExpression:
    value=BoolValue;

/*-----------------------------------ENUM_TERMINALS-----------------------------------*/
enum UnaryOperator:
    ARITH_NEGATE='-' | BOOL_NEGATE='!' | BIN_NEGATE='~' | BIN_AND='&' | BIN_OR='|' | BIN_XOR='^';

enum BoolValue:
    TRUE='true' | FALSE='false';
```

Everything here seemed to work well, but when I added the *BitSliceExpression* and tried to process the grammar, I've received the following error:

**The Error:**

```
error(211): ../org.example.expressions/src-gen/org/example/expressions/parser/antlr/internal/InternalExpressions.g:1626:3: [fatal] rule ruleFieldOperationExpression has non-LL(*) decision due to recursive rule invocations reachable from alts 1,4.  Resolve by left-factoring or using syntactic predicates or using backtrack=true option.
```

After a bit of testing, I reached the conclusion that this problem is caused by ambiguity between *BitSliceExpression* And *CollectionAccessExpression*

```
//BitSliceExpression example:
[5:3]
//CollectionAccessExpression example:
[5]
```

I have very little knowledge of Xtext, Antlr3, and parsing algorithms in general,
but I can only assume that since *Expression* is a recursive rule, the parser is unable too look past it and check for the semicolon literal, which is the distinguishing mark between
*BitSliceExpression* And *CollectionAccessExpression* at runtime, and thus an ambiguity is born.

I have spent a long time researching this issue, but due to my limited knowledge I have not been able to find a proper solution, and I would greatly appreciate help.

(Please tell me if more information about my project is required)

Comment: The problem is that the rule you added conflicts with FieldOperationExpression, which is what the error message says, not CollectionAccessExpression. The problem is that FieldOperationExpression has an alt for `'[' Expression ']'`, but you also define that in BitSliceExpression, so it can't distinguish between the two. One solution is to just change the FieldOperationExpression rule: `FieldOperationExpression: UnaryExpression ( '[' Expression ( ':' Expression )? ']' | '.' RULE_ID '(' ( Expression ( ',' Expression )* )? ')' | '.' RULE_ID )* ;` (ignoring the tree construction code).

Comment: https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/307_special_languages.html#expressions

Comment: Actually, the replacement rule I gave works, but my explanation was incorrect. The conflict is in the common `'[' Expression` sentential strings between BitSliceExpression and FieldOperationExpression. Your grammar would work just fine in Antlr4, however--I tested it.

Comment: I have tried this method, and it worked, but creating relevant AST branches is very important in my project. Also, I much prefer to use Xtext (Which uses Antlr3), because of all the IDE features it provides. Is there any other way to solve this issue?

Comment: Keep with XText for now and just modify the AST construction for each alt of the rule.

Comment: That sounds good, but I'm new to Xtext and I don't know how to implement that. can you show me?